# How to extend DelegatingAuthenticationProvider in Micronaut

Tags: micronaut

Following this doc:
 http://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-database-authentication-provider-groovy/guide/index.html
you can create a db/dao for auth/auth.  If you provide implementations for UserFetcher, PasswordEncoder and AuthoritiesFetcher you are good to go with the default DelegatingAuthenticationProvider.  By doing this you get /login, /logout /refresh endpoints with jwt cookies or bearer and encryption.  I would like to both extend the default behavior and configure it as the only authprovider.   If anyone has done this, it would be helpful to know.

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't a super great fit for StackOverflow because there isn't really a specific answer.  The solution will really depend on knowing more about your environment, like how you are doing authentication.

A good starting point might be to consider an authentication provider and that thing could do whatever you want to do at auth time, including keeping track of authentication requests over a period of time.  See https://docs.micronaut.io/1.0.1/guide/index.html#authenticationProviders for more info.

Comment: You haven't included any info on what you want to do if you detect what you consider to be too many attempts in the last 60 seconds, which might affect the recommended solution as well.

Comment: Good point.  I've changed the title and description to be more specific.

Comment: For the benefit of others reading this answer later, note that the question as worded right now is a fundamentally different question than the one I answered.  Best of luck!